# drupalPost() equivalent

Tags: php, html, drupal, function

I need help. I'm looking for a [$this->drupalPost](http://drupal.org/node/265762) equivalent. Something that I can implement in a none webtestcase environment.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Google seems to yield nothing.

Comment: Try @Matthew's solution below. That's the other alternative in Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal API has a [drupal_http_request](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/6) function which can make POST requests as well as GET requests.